# React - Trap focus within functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I have a slideout panel. It has several options you can tab through. I want to prevent the the user from being able to tab to the content behind the slideout panel while it is open.

I tried using `react-focus-trap` but it simply does not work anymore (no longer maintained) There are no errors, it's just that nothing gets trapped.

I tried using `focus-react-trap` and this does not work with my functional component. I get the following error:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

And then this error as well:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
    at tabbable
```

How can I trap keyboard focus in my slideout panel while active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`react-focus-lock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-focus-lock), or [`react-focus-on`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-focus-on) to also trap focus for screen-readers.